# how to skip_callback while building has_many relationship objects in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, model-associations

how to skip_callback while building has_many relationship objects in rails 5

Consider below case

```
class Customer
  has_many :resources
end

class Resource
  attr_accessor: :skip_callback
  belongs_to :customer
  after_commit :data_calculation, unless: :skip_callback

  def data_calculation
    # logic goes here
  end
end

customer = Customer.new
customer.resources.build({name: 'abc'})
customer.save
```

I want skip callback of associated object.

Can we do this while building object?

Answer (score 0):

found solution,

```
customer = Customer.new
customer.resources.build({name: 'abc', skip_callback: true})
customer.save
```

passing attr_accessor as params will set callbacks condition value also.

Comment: Neat. And the callbacks will be called when it saves?

Comment: No, as I have added condition to the callback